# Difficulty with Subfig: Aligning Figures on Centerline

Tags: floats, subfloats

I am trying to center figures along their horizontal axis using the example in Sec. 5.4 of `subfig`, but no matter what I do, this is what I'm seeing. Even when I exaggerate the figures' widths so that there's no way they could overlap, like so:

[image: the problem]

I am using the following code and packages. The block of code was copied directly from the example in the `subfig` documentation.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\graphicspath{{Figures/}}
\newsavebox{\tempbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}%
  \centering
  \sbox{\tempbox}{\includegraphics[width=1in]{I_Am_A_Red_Square}}%
  \subfloat[Big figure]{\usebox{\tempbox}}%
  \qquad
  \subfloat[Small figure]{%
    \vbox to \ht\tempbox{%
      \vfil
      \includegraphics[width=0.25in]{I_Am_A_Red_Square}
      \vfil}}%
  \caption{Two more sub-floats.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I would have preferred to use subcaption, but it does not appear to be compatible with the template I'm required to use for my dissertation.

What can I do to fix this?

**Edit:** I wasn't clear about the scope of the problem. I am trying to get the figures to sit next to each other, not stack vertically. Everything I do seems to just adjust the figures' sizes, still one above the other, not side-by-side. I'll try and come up with a MWE.

**Edit #2:** Updated with a proper code example. This is the document generated using the above code:

[image: Update #3]

**Edit #3:** Updated with a more illustrative code example, one which does not use `demo` in `graphicx`. The image above has been replaced with the one using the updated code. I am trying to center the two figures on their respective horizontal axes, like this:

```
 ______
|      |    ___
|      |   |   |
|      |   |___|
|______|
```

I have also updated the post tile to clarify the "centerline" issue. I'm bad at explaining things today.

Comment: I apologize, I should have been clearer, and will update the post to clarify. I am trying to get the figures _next to_ each other, not stacked vertically. Everything I do just results in them changing size, still stacked vertically.

Comment: We need something we can compile in order to reproduce the problem. Or try `floatrow`.

Comment: @cfr I realized that after posting. I'm working on one now.

Comment: Duly updated with a proper example. My apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the output you were after?

**Output**

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
    \subfloat[Small figure]{%
    \begin{minipage}[c][1in]{1in}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.5in]{example-image-a}
    \end{minipage}}%
    \hspace{\tabcolsep}
    \subfloat[Big figure]{%
        \begin{minipage}[c][1in]{1in}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1in]{example-image-b}
    \end{minipage}}
    \caption{Two more sub-floats.}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: @amizener Then I don't undestand what you desire. Please explain better. I thought you wanted the two figures side-by-side. And what do you mean by you last comment here? conseals what?

Comment: I apologize, I hit enter too early and then my internet immediately went down for a few minutes. I was not intending to be rude.

No, but it appears that that is because the 'demo' option in `graphics` hides the problem. This code does not center the two figures next to each other, which is what I am trying to do. I will update the original post with a more accurate image and code.

Comment: @amizener looks centred to me.

Comment: On the page, yes, but not with respect to their respective horizontal axes.

Comment: @amizener okey, see updated answer

Comment: That appears to work, thank you. Am I correct in thinking that `[c][1in]{1in}` is the dimensions of each minipage? If not, what does that do?

Comment: Center vertically, height. Width. Here, the dimensions are set to the biggest of the figures. Dimensions should probably be calculated, use a savebox to do so.